# Getting "Unable to set CurrentPage property of PivotField class" error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use VBA to automatically update the pivot table filter based off the user's selection from a cell entry. I believe everything is working correctly up to line 11 which says "Field.CurrentPage = NewCat". This is where the issue lies. The code clears my filter as instructed in the previous line but when it gets to the code instructing it to select the new data I get the error that reads "Run-time error 1004. Unable to set CurrentPage property of PivotField class".

Below is the what I have so far and I'm just looking how to revise row 11 so it selects the new input to use in the pivot table filter. I appreciate any help I can get on this. I'm very new to vba & have struggled with this for far too long!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("C3:C4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

Set pt = Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("[Range].[Site].[Site]")
NewCat = Worksheets("Interface").Range("C3").Value

With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

Hoping this will be beneficial to someone who is experiencing the same "1004 error" when attempting to set the "CurrentPage" property of the PivotField class.

For me, it finally worked when I replaced the "CurrentPage" property with "CurrentPageName" as such:

```
With pf
  .ClearAllFilters
  MsgBox "The PivotField is: " & pf.Value
  MsgBox "The current PivotField value is: " & .CurrentPageName
  .CurrentPageName = NewCat
End With
```

My pivot table have what was called "page level filters":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poKCi.png)

Comment: YES! Thank you, after so much searching this finally worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just a matter of syntax.

If you change:

```
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With
```

to:

```
With Field
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = NewCat
End With

pt.RefreshTable
```

It will work.

Notice, that I work directly with the `Field` in the `With Block`.

To illustrate further, if you change it to the following, it will work as well:

```
With pt.PivotFields(Field.Name)
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = NewCat
End With

pt.RefreshTable
```

So, you basically need to work directly with objects and you need to qualify the objects, properties, methods / etc. with a `.`

Comment: Hey Scott - thanks so much for answering and the information. Unfortunately I am still receiving the same error message with both alternative examples you provided.

I'm not sure if this is relevant but when creating the PivotTable this is related to, I selected "Add this data to the Data Model" under "Choose whether you want to analyze multiple tables". This was because I needed to access the "Distinct count" feature in the PivotTable, which is only accessible if I select this option.

This may be relevant as the VBA script seems to work fine when I do not select this option.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and changed the fields *name* and *range value*:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvtTest").PivotFields("Week") 
    .ClearAllFilters 
    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=ActiveSheet.Range("K1").Value 
End With
```

[1] http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=169855

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found a solution that worked for me as none of the above seemed to.  This is what I would change:

```
NewCat = Worksheets("Interface").Range("C3").Value

With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With
```

To:

```
NewCat = Array("[Range].[Site].&[" & Worksheets("Interface").Range("C3").Value & "]")

With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.VisbleItemsList = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several answers here with no luck.  Then I ran a loop through the PivotItems collection under the PivotField to inspect the PivotItems properties in the Locals window.

If you first set the field to a variable like *myField* then you can loop through as such:

```
For Each pItem in myField.PivotItems
    debug.print "Item Caption: """ & pItem.Caption """"
    debug.print "Item Name: """ & pItem.Name """"
Next
```

What this showed me is that my field had extra spaces at the end, so the value I was trying to set at the filter was not exactly what I had in my list.

This led to the multiple-values option:

```
For Each pItem In myField.PivotItems
    If Not pItem.Caption Like myFilterValue & "*" Then
        pItem.Visible = False
    Else
        pItem.Visible = True
    End If
Next
```

However, since I really only wanted one value I went back and dealt with the unwanted spaces.

There could be other things, but this may be one thing to check.

Answer (score -2):

Removing the variable declaration of `NewCat` worked for me. Either delete the line or comment it out

```
'Dim NewCat As String
```

Comment: And did this also work when `Option Explicit` is at the top of the code page, as it should be? I doubt it, since then the variable would not be declared. Instead, try using `Dim NewCat as Variant` and see if that works for you. If it does, that means the `String` variable type is incorrect for the type of data that needs to be passed to the method...