# vba error "unable to set currentpage property of the pivotfield class"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set the page filter on pivot table based on the value in a cell.  I am a novice with vba, so I found some code to start with.  I am getting an error "unable to set the currentpage property of the pivotfield class" on the command `field.currentpage = newcat`

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As Long

Set pt = Worksheets("REPORT - Acct Plan").PivotTables("PT_Activities")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("[Activities].[BPID].[BPID]")
NewCat = Worksheets("REPORT - Acct Plan").Range("B1").Value

Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

I did some research and found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817213/getting-unable-to-set-currentpage-property-of-pivotfield-class-error), but it was never answered completely.  I also verified the data types of my control cell B1 and pivot table were the same.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!