# PivotTable CurrentPage property - getting "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm brand new to VBA (this is Day 2!). I'm attempting to set a PivotTable filter to match a combo box user selection. I found some code to set the filter to the contents of a cell when that cell is selected, and I've modified it by putting it in a sub for a button so that the code isn't activated until the button is clicked.

```
Sub Generate_Report()

'PLAN - Changes Plan filter value for PivotTable to value in Plan combo box, which is 
'linked to cell D9
'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim PlanFilter As PivotField
Dim NewPlan As String

Set pt = Worksheets("Pivot Table").PivotTables("PivotTable_Parameters")
Set PlanFilter = pt.PivotFields("Plan")
NewPlan = Worksheets("Report Options").Range("D9").Value

'Update and refresh the PIVOT table
With pt
PlanFilter.ClearAllFilters
pt.PivotFields("Plan").CurrentPage = NewPlan
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

(I wish I could find the page where I got the code - thank you to the online VBA community for your help in getting me started!)

I've changed some variable names in the original code to better match the context. PlanFilter was previously called `Field`. The `.CurrentPage` line previously read: `Field.CurrentPage=NewCat`

I'm having trouble with the `.CurrentPage` line. It worked fine before I changed the variable name, but once I did, I got an "application-defined or object-defined" error. I changed the field reference to the longer reference that you see here, and it initially worked, then it didn't.

A similar issue using the same code is addressed at [Getting "Unable to set CurrentPage property of PivotField class" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817213/getting-unable-to-set-currentpage-property-of-pivotfield-class-error), but I was unable to leave a comment there. I tried the change that Scott suggested:

```
With PlanFilter
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = NewPlan
End With
```

... but I'm still getting the error.

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Kate

Comment: `With pt
pt.PivotFields` is redundant. I would not be using `pt` after you have already set it with your `With pt` statement.

Comment: Thank you, Salvador. Can you tell me what code I would replace it with? I'm very, very new to this.

Also, thank you for the edits! How did you change the bits of field within the text the way you did?

Comment: If you add a ` character before and after your code statement, it will change them to be "snippets" instead of just words.

Comment: I will add my suggested changes as an answer. I don't expect it to fix your initial issue, but it will at least add value to your coding legibility.

Comment: @KateGrafel the code that you took from Scott Holtzman works, it depends how your `PivotTable` is structured. Can you edit your post and add a screen-shot of your Pivot-Table ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would change:

```
With pt
PlanFilter.ClearAllFilters
pt.PivotFields("Plan").CurrentPage = NewPlan
pt.RefreshTable
End With
```

to

```
With pt
  .PivotFields("Plan").ClearAllFilters
  .PivotFields("Plan").CurrentPage = NewPlan
  .RefreshTable
End With
```

Comment: Salvador, thank you for your help! I understand now that, due to the use of the variables, some of the commands within the "With pt" section duplicated the "pt" reference and some didn't.

Comment: HTH! I figured that was the case considering `pt` was being used in the `With` and the `pt.` statements. It's best practice to only use a variable once per statement, but I wasn't aware it would break anything. The more you know!