# Report Filter on a single item in pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have the following code to ensure that only a single value is selected on the relevant pivot field - however I keep getting the error "unable to set the currentpage property of the pivot field" - I don't understand why as I used a the same code for a different filter.

```
Sub filters()

Dim PRC As PivotField

Sheets("workings-calc").Select

Set PRC = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("PR_CD")

PRC.ClearAllFilters

PRC.CurrentPage = "PR-500001"

End Sub
```

Appreciate any help on this. Have spent far too long trying to get this to work without success :/

Comment: Maybe this other thread can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817213/getting-unable-to-set-currentpage-property-of-pivotfield-class-error

Comment: Are you sure that value exists in your data set?

Comment: Is PRC a PageField? CurrentPage only works with them. There is a workaround for other fields, though.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while manually applying filter options on pivot/

Comment: Value exists in data set. @jeffreyweir its a row in the pivot table rather than page field. Can you help with the workaround?

Comment: Sure thing. Will post link and answer within next few hours

Comment: Can you clarify the use-case for this? Are you trying to ensure that the PivotTable is *always* filtered on PR-200001? Or do you want the user to be able to filter on *any* one item (but limit the selection to *just* one item)?

Comment: Just to update on this. I managed to figure out a workaround to get what I needed.  The code I used was:

Answer (score 0):

The following code works and gets me the desired output.

```
 for each itm1 in prc.pivotitems
 if item 1.name  = "PR-500001" then
 else
 itm1.visible = false
 next
```

the above code leaves only the filter specified selected on the pivot field.

Thanks for all the input.