# Can't synchronize pivot tables created with Power Pivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerpivot

I'm trying to use VBA to synchronize the filters of two pivot tables that are created with PowerPivot ... I want to apply the filter settings in pf "OU" from pt "pt_ECperMonth" to another pt named "pt_SurfacePerMonth" ... 
Below the code I thought would do the job .... on .CurrentPage= "(All)" (line4) I get Runtime error 1004 "Unable to set the CurrentPage property of the PivotField class"

Somebody who knows how to get out of this issue? 
one remark : I used to successfully apply the same method to synchronize pt that were not created with PowerPivot!

```
Set pf = Sheets("Surface per month").PivotTables("pt_SurfacePerMonth").PivotFields("[SML_Sites1].[OU].[OU]")
With pf
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = "(All)"
    For Each pi In Sheets("EC per month").PivotTables("pt_ECPerMonth").PivotFields("[SML_Sites].[OU].[OU]").PivotItems
        .PivotItems(pi.Name).Visible = pi.Visible
    Next pi
End With
```

Comment: Possible duplicate, look at this first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817213/getting-unable-to-set-currentpage-property-of-pivotfield-class-error

Comment: You can solve this problem without VBA. Instead of page filter, create a slicer, and set it to control both pivot tables. Simple and reliable.