# Filter Data Model PivotTable by cell value

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have tried many different solutions like the ones given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817213/getting-unable-to-set-currentpage-property-of-pivotfield-class-error?noredirect=1) but none of them work for me.

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim Field As PivotField
    Dim NewCat As Integer '<-I have tred String or not defining it at all

    Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("myPivot")
    Set Field = pt.PivotFields("[Test].[Category].[Category]")
    NewCat = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value

     With pt
        Field.ClearAllFilters
        Field.CurrentPage = NewCat '<- Here I have tried many variations
        pt.RefreshTable
    End With

End Sub
```

I am mostly getting a 1004 error at the line `Field.CurrentPage`. The 'Category' variable that I am trying to filter is made out of integers. The whole Pivot Table is based on a Data Model. I can't figure out what is wrong, help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, finally. The issue is that the NewCat value must be in the format `[QueryName].[Category].&[CategoryValue]`. I am guessing this has to do with the Pivot being used on a Data Model.

So I used a simple string concenation to get my value in the correct format:

```
myValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value
leftP = "&["
rightP = "]"
NewCat = "[Test].[Category]." & leftP& myValue & rightP
```

Hopefully this saves others time...

Answer (score 0):

took inspiration.

```
Sub FilterPageValue()

    Dim newfilter
    Dim value As String
    value = Worksheets("Master").Range("A104").value
  
    leftP = "&["
    rightP = "]"
        
        newfilter = Array("[0_Stock].[Vendor Code]." & leftP & value & rightP)
        
        
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot").PivotFields( _
        "[0_Stock].[Vendor Code].[Vendor Code]")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .VisibleItemsList = newfilter
    
  End With
  
End Sub
```