# Choose positions in the pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that creates a PivotTable for me with the fields I want. However, I would like them to choose the indicated values.This is what the table looks like at the start
[image]

here is what I would like e.g.
[image]

this is my code:

```
Set sh_s = wbMe.Sheets("kredyty")
 lr1 = sh_s.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 ptver1 = 6
 tbName1 = "Tabela przestawna"
 Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
 Set sh_d = ActiveSheet
 ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
   SourceData:=sh_s.Name & "!R1C1:R" & lr1 & "C58", Version:=ptver).CreatePivotTable _
   TableDestination:=sh_d.Name & "!R3C1", TableName:=tbName1, _
   DefaultVersion:=ptver1
 With sh_d.PivotTables(tbName1)
  With .PivotFields("CRD_RWG")
   .Orientation = xlPageField
     .Position = 1
   With sh_d.PivotTables(tbName1)
  With .PivotFields("NEW_DEFAULT")
     .Orientation = xlPageField
     .Position = 1
   End With
   .AddDataField .PivotFields("CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN"), "Suma z Ekspozycji", xlSum
   .AddDataField .PivotFields("CRD_KOR_DC_FIN"), "Suma z Korekty", xlSum
       End With
```

Comment: Did you try recording a macro while setting the value of the fields?

Comment: Nope im going to try

Comment: `.PivotFields("CRD_RWG").CurrentPage = 1` (eg) should do it.  e.g see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817213/getting-unable-to-set-currentpage-property-of-pivotfield-class-error